# How to validate fields inside object in typescript using typeguards

Tags: javascript, typescript, express, typeguards

I am processing some data in my backend (written in Typescript) provided via a form in html. Before writing the data to the database, I perform validations using type guards.

```
let myObject = { property: parseProperty(property) }
```

where the type definition for "property" is given as:

```
interface PropertyType = { 
    Field1: string; 
    Field2: string; 
  }
```

The property object is first parsed via the following type-guard:

```
const parseProperty = (property: unknown): PropertyType => {
  if (!property || !isPropertyEntry(property)) {
    throw new Error("Incorrect or missing property entry")
  }
  return property;
```

Then we use the typeguard below (which is incomplete) to validate property's objects fields.

```
const isPropertyEntry = (property : unknown): property is PropertyType => {
  if( !('Field1' in property) || !('Field2' in property) ) {    // <--- invalid statement
    throw new Error("Incorrect or missing field/s in property");
  } 
  ...
  ...

}
```

TS throws an error for these two statements: `'Field1' in property` & `'Field2' in property`:
`Object is of type 'unknown'.ts(2571)`

My question is how would I do a proper validation of the object 'property' and make sure `Field1` & `Field2` exist and are correct type?

Comment: Use the `PropertyType` interface instead of `unknown`, or supply it via a generic type argument (e.g. `function isPropertyEntry<T>(property: T) ...`

Answer (score 1):

It does not look like you want to have a type guard. Since you want to throw an `Error` when `property` is not a `PropertyType`, you probably need an [assertion function](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html#assertion-functions).

```
function assertIsPropertyEntry(property: any): asserts property is PropertyType {
  if (
    typeof property !== "object" 
    || !property 
    || !('Field1' in property) 
    || !('Field2' in property)
    || typeof property.Field1 !== "string"
    || typeof property.Field2 !== "string"
  ) {
    throw new Error("Incorrect or missing field/s in property");
  } 
}

const parseProperty = (property: unknown): PropertyType => {
  assertIsPropertyEntry(property)
  return property
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgApQPYAdpgJ4AqeOyA3sgFDLXIBiwEANgCYCMAXMgM5hSgDmAbko06DFgCZOPPiCGUAvpQoUYAVxAIwwDCGRwuXXAEku6bLjwBRcFDwAKLJhxR8nOCDwBKd4dxdkJwtXPGRgAPMXfCISUiowmHt46nwcDBhA50tkAEIAXjzkACIMACMAKwgtIpEaAB863KCo0OTkBtz7AHJ6JjYusL1myy9a6g6c7t7JAdBM4PwvNo7UiHT5loA6abZcguKZASLlxtX14ZDt8WYJPcKiw7lj6lG40TAAC0wAd2QQCF%20VigmCg9iKxk0GGBVTAyChyAAtuEuAJkDBrgB6AJzC74IpeQTxJQUBQqCgIXQ8QJwKBGSLZQqOLIhTgaADWIAw3xAPjQzOixBQeQAfGR4gYjK5TPSQjZeA5cd54lAIGA1FAhvy8CSgA)